# Why does not Vuelta have young rider jersey?

Tags: ranking, cycling

While both [Tour de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tour_de_France_secondary_classification_winners) and [Giro d'Italia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Giro_d%27Italia_classification_winners) have young rider classification, [Vuelta a España](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vuelta_a_Espa%C3%B1a_classification_winners) does not have a competition for young riders.

Is it known for what reasons decision not to have young riders classification was made? Has a possibility of young riders classification at Vuelta been discussed?

EDIT: In 2019, the combination classification was discontinued and young rider classification was introduced instead. See Wikipedia article [Combination classification in the Vuelta a España](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_classification_in_the_Vuelta_a_Espa%C3%B1a) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Combination_classification_in_the_Vuelta_a_Espa%C3%B1a&oldid=908695060)) and [Vuelta a Espana introduces young rider jersey in 2019](http://www.cyclingnews.com/news/vuelta-a-espana-introduces-young-rider-jersey-in-2019/) at Cyclingnews ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190405144900/http://www.cyclingnews.com/news/vuelta-a-espana-introduces-young-rider-jersey-in-2019/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has not been considered yet, as the general director of La Vuelta says, since there is the combination ranking which makes it add up to four classifications overall.

Wikipedia in Spanish states:

> Otra característica diferenciadora sobre otras [Grandes Vueltas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandes_Vueltas) es que nunca ha existido clasificación de los jóvenes y en su lugar se utiliza la clasificación de la combinada que tiene en cuenta los puestos de los corredores en la clasificación general, la clasificación a puntos y la de la montaña.

Which translates as:

> Another unique characteristic versus the rest of [Grand Tours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour_(cycling)) is the fact that no youth classification has ever existed. In its place, a combination classification is used, taking into account the overall, the points and the mountain classification ranking of the cyclists.

There is an [interview with La Vuelta's general director Javier Guillén](http://www.ciclismoafondo.es/competicion/entrevistas/articulo/Entrevista-a-Javier-Guillen-director-de-la-Vuelta-a-Espana) from back in 2014 where you can read:

> Question: Hablemos de una cuestión llamativa. La Vuelta a España es la única de las grandes vueltas que no tiene la maillot al mejor joven. En cambio existe la combinada que es una clasificación algo abstracta y difícil de entender a primera vista. ¿Os planteáis incluir un maillot al mejor joven en las próximas ediciones?
>
> Answer: Tenemos el mismo número de maillot que las otras grandes, cuatro. No tenemos clasificación de los jóvenes, y no digo que no la debiéramos tener, pero hoy por hoy tenemos la combinada cuenta con un sponsor muy identificado con esta clasificación que lleva 19 años patrocinando a la Vuelta. La combinada es una seña de la Vuelta a España puesto que es la única carrera que la tiene y queremos mantenerlo. Si algún día surge alguna posibilidad que dé pie a ello se podría incluir la clasificación de los jóvenes pero actualmente creemos que el podio está suficientemente completo en su situación actual.

Which translates to:

> Question: Let's now talk about a flashy thing. La Vuelta a España is the only one among Grand Tours not having a maillot for the young riders. Instead, there is the *combination*, a rather abstract ranking and difficult to understand on first sight. Are you considering including a maillot to the best young cyclist in the upcoming editions?
>
> Answer: We do have the same amount of maillots as the other ones; this is, four. We do not have young classification, and I am not saying we should not have it, but nowadays we have the combination with a sponsor which is very much identified with this ranking since it has been sponsoring La Vuelta for 19 years. The combination is a distinguishing mark of La Vuelta, since it is the only race having it and we want to keep it like this. If we ever get the chance, we could include the young rider classification, but nowadays we think that the podium is full enough.